# jqGrid Tree expand node on DragNDrop over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqtree

i have 2 Grids(`*#list1, #list2*`)and want to Drag something from `*#list2*` to `*#list1*`. When Hovering over an node, the node expand like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrOgR.png) .
I still have to draggable element on Cursor and when im focusing row 3,
it should focus setSelection on

> "00000010 Testkonto LVL"

but what it does, is setSelection on

> "Gruppe 2"

See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRmHL.png).

When i leave `#list1` with the draggable element and focus it again. The Rows are selectable.

My Question is, when adding Elements with `addChildNode` how can i reset the positions in `#list1` that the `over` function can focus on the expanded leafs.

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery-ui.js file i just changed `refreshPositions` to `true`

```
$.widget("ui.draggable", $.ui.mouse, {
    version: "1.10.3",
    widgetEventPrefix: "drag",
    options: {
        addClasses: true,
        appendTo: "parent",
        axis: false,
        connectToSortable: false,
        containment: false,
        cursor: "auto",
        cursorAt: false,
        grid: false,
        handle: false,
        helper: "original",
        iframeFix: false,
        opacity: false,
        refreshPositions: true,
        revert: false,
        revertDuration: 500,
        scope: "default",
        scroll: true,
        scrollSensitivity: 20,
        scrollSpeed: 20,
        snap: false,
        snapMode: "both",
        snapTolerance: 20,
        stack: false,
        zIndex: false,

        // callbacks
        drag: null,
        start: null,
        stop: null
    },
```

Is there a way to dont do it in the `jquery-ui.js` file rather than in an external javascript file? i dont want to change something in the "Template"